# RDP connnection IDLE time warning

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, group-policy

[image]

I am working with one Group Policy setting which is for Session time limits (picture attached). While testing, I found out the warning which shows up at 2 min mark is really subtle.

If rdp connection is minimized, user wont even know if warning came up or not. Second downside is, it disconnects the rdp connection after idle time expires (15 min) which is not what I am looking for.

Is there any better option which would alert user at 2 min mark prominently. Like it pops up the rdp connection before expiring.

Answer (score 0):

No there's no way to change the UX for the pop-up warning. This setting is for the servers to reclaim resources, not as a reminder to the users that they should be working.

As far as the time out action, which is defined in the last setting there 'Terminate session when time limit is reached', you can either disconnect the session (which means the user can resume where they were when they reconnect) or you can terminate which logs them off (enable).

Comment: Make sense! Is there any possibility through powershell scripting?

Comment: This is completely theoretical because I don't have time to test it. If the RDP timout popup logs an event entry in the event log, you could create a scheduled task that executes when that event id is logged. The scheduled task PowerShell script / command could write a window with a custom message. Unfortunately, you'd still be at the mercy of the 2 minute warning.